# defaultDisplay in kotlin is deprecated, what method should I use instead?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I want to take the size of my image, I tried to use defaultDisplay and it turns out that the method is deprecated, what method can I use instead?

```
fun getScaledBitmap(path: String, activity: Activity):Bitmap{
    val size = Point()
    activity.windowManager.defaultDisplay.getSize(size)
    return getScaledBitmap(path, size.x, size.y)
}

fun getScaledBitmap(path: String, destWidth: Int, destHeight: Int): Bitmap{
   ...
}
```

Comment: Have a look here: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/util/DisplayMetrics

Answer (score 1):

```
File file = new File(fullFilePath);
long length = file.length();
length = length/1024;
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Image size:"+length+"KB",
Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Have This in Java